# After migrating to .NET 5 shows an error "Use of unassigned local variable" for out parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-5

```
public bool TryGetCustomerId(out Guid customerId)
{
    customerId = Guid.Empty;
    if (_contextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(CustomKnownHeaders.CustomerId,
        out var values) ?? false)
    {
        return Guid.TryParse(values.FirstOrDefault(), out customerId);
    }

    return false;
}
```

After migrating from .NET Core 3.1 to .NET 5 shows an error "Use of unassigned local variable" for out parameter variable.

Error shows in "values" variable.
Error - "Use of unassigned local variable 'values'"

Comment: `TryGetValue(...) ?? false` seems weird since `TryGetValue()` returns `bool` which is never `null`. What happens if you take away the `?? false` part?

Comment: @Xiang but `HttpContext?.` might have propagated a null to there

Comment: @CaiusJard Ah, indeed! Sorry, missed that question mark there.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you migrate to .NET 6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a bug or at least limitation in the compiler. It apparently doesn't realize that the line:

```cs
return Guid.TryParse(values.FirstOrDefault(), out customerId);
```

will never execute unless `_contextAccessor.HttpContext` is non-`null`, `TryGetValue` is called and `values` is assigned a value.

Notably changing `?? false` to `== true` (which is how I usually handle this exact scenario) doesn't make a difference. Apparently, the fact that `TryGetValue` might not be called is enough for the compiler to treat any subsequent use of `values` as potentially unassigned, even though `values` CANNOT be unassigned in the only branch in which it's being used.

It's hard to look at this as anything other than a bug in the compiler which should probably be reported at https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn.

**Edit**
This does not appear to be an issue in Visual Studio 2022 (even in .NET5 projects), so it seems MS did recognize the bug and fix it. I only see it when opening and compiling the project using 2019.

Answer (score 5):

> After migrating from .Net core 3.1 to .Net 5 shows an error "Use of unassigned local variable"

I tested something similar in netcore3.1 and got the same error..

[image]Are you really sure the code works in netcore3.1?

Looks like this is one of those cases where the compiler just can't tell the variable has been definitely assigned - see "conditional access coalesced to a bool constant" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/improved-definite-assignment). You might have to rewrite your code to help it out:

```
public bool TryGetCustomerId(out Guid customerId)
{
    customerId = Guid.Empty;
    string[] values = null;
    if (_contextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(CustomKnownHeaders.CustomerId,
        out values) ?? false)
    {
        return Guid.TryParse(values.FirstOrDefault(), out customerId);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hey,
Yes it's working in .Net core 3.1. But not in .Net 5

Comment: @Hash_Dew: Regardless, this should workaround the issue. Did you try the proposed code to explicitly initialize the variable?